# Form values lost on Previous page when innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, forms, caching, innerhtml

I got a form that I display using .innerHTML

When I submit, and go back to the form page, the form is empty.

Why?

Here is a jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/ft5bjhqq/3/

(Enter values in the forms, submit, go back and see the difference [Screen3](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/985797screen3.png).

```
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = ''+
  '<form method="post" action="azerty.php">'+
    '<input type="text"> '+
    '<input type="submit" value="OK">'+
  '</form>';
```

Is there an easy solution for the 2nd form to copy the behavior of the first one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you expect the content of the form is?

Comment: The content I enter in the form before submit. 

[Screen1 : enter values](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/421006screen1.png)

[Screen2 : submit](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/548033screen2.png)

[Screen3 : go back to previous page](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/985797screen3.png)

Comment: Why don't you use hidden input for populating the value, each time when your page is loaded, it loads your test with same .innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this is best way or not, but it will solve your problem.

Edited your fiddle, check

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ft5bjhqq/5/)

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="copValue()" action="azerty.php">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>

<br>

innerhtml
<div id="test" > </div>
<input type="hidden" id="iAmHidden">
```

**JS**

```
var value=document.getElementById('iAmHidden').value;


  function copValue () {
    document.getElementById('iAmHidden').value = document.getElementById('formText').value;
    return true;
  }

 document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = ''+
  '<form method="post" onsubmit="copValue()" action="azerty.php">'+
    '<input type="text" id="formText" value="'+value+'"> '+
    '<input type="submit" value="OK">'+
  '</form>';
```

Hope it solve your problem !!

Comment: Thank you for that answer! I use innerHTML to change pages without reloading the whole page. (menu/footer not reloaded) So I can keep music playing in between/after the page change. Because of that I can't set the hidden input html before my script display the form. (the form is on a page that is displayed via the script)

Comment: I can still use your way setting the hidden input on all the pages of my website, but I think there can be another way

Comment: Yeah, you can give it as answer if it worked for you !!, Thanks !!